# Consumer component for file streaming

Tags: apache-camel

I am using consumer.receive to get the file and it's in the exchange object.
We have given timeout as 10 sec.
Most of the time we are able get the file. But sometime it's giving null value.
Is there any way to avoid this issue?

Answer (score 0):

No, if you get `null` then its because the timeout was hit after 10 second and there was no file available within that time. You can avoid it only by using a higher timeout value.

Also when you ask questions then provide more details, you question is very vague and only a few people can help so. Provide more details, such as code samples and show more effort what you have done first.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I will try to put more details .  I am 100% sure that the file was available at the location when consumer trying to receive the file. This scenario is happening in production version intermittently. Please let me know if you need any other information. The actual file is placed in the amazon efs location.